# unable to use cocoapods after updating

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, rubygems, cocoapods

I have updates Ruby , Gems and Cocoapods on my mac OSX 10.9.5, after the update I am unable to execute the command

```
pod install
```

I'm getting the below error from terminal

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:13:in `report': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:61:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:300:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:274:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:264:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.2/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I have created a Podfile with the below content

```
platform :ios, ‘7.1’

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.3’
```

Cocoapods worked perfectly before the update. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This character " ‘ " is incomatible with cocoapods in first line.
You should use this instead " ' ". So your podfile should be like this:

```
platform :ios, '7.1'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.4'
```

Comment: thanks a lost, it actually worked the weird thing is that the quotes didn't appear to be wrong on TextEdit ...

Comment: Thanks you Saved ME... The Problem was that I Was Editing it in TextView instead of the Xcode, probably TextEdit Converts these little annoyers to "'"

Comment: Priceless! I would never think of that!

Comment: Editing the PodFile in TextWrangler fixed this for me, and as stated, removed the comma. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the use of incorrect quotes around the iOS version. Make sure all your quotes are ' and not ‘ or ’.