# Unable to run pod install. getting the following error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, cocoapods

```
ankit-srivastava-iMac:ixigo-travel ankit$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.8 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Analyzing dependencies
2016-04-18 20:08:36.725 ruby[98876:1962512] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 956. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:13:in `report': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:61:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:374:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:315:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

**Podfile contents**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ixigo-travel' do

    # UI Elements
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'PureLayout'
    pod 'StatefulViewController'

    pod 'RazzleDazzle'

    # Utilities
    pod 'KeychainSwift'
    pod 'HanekeSwift'

    # API
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'ObjectMapper'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'

    # Facebook
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

    # Google
    pod 'Google/SignIn'

    # Crashlytics
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'

    # Analytics
    pod 'CleverTap-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'

end
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of your podfile ?

Comment: @Mindhavok Added the contents, please check.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383635/unable-to-use-cocoapods-after-updating